# Display a custom login control in Windows Phone with Mvvm light

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

Ok, so what I am looking to do is to display some sort of login control (maybe a UserControl with a TextBox and PasswordBox) when the app is started.

In a non-mvvm situation, a way of doing this would be to use the PopUp primitive control, add the usercontrol as a child element and off you go.

In an MVVM situation, i'm a bit confused about how you would achieve a simmilar result.

I have looked into messaging with the DialogMessage and this is fine for displaying a typical MessageBox, but what about a custom usercontrol?

any help would be fantastic! I can't seem to find any demo code of this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a MVVM situation you can use a delegate to let your View open the dialog when the ViewModel requests it.

You define a delegate at the VM:

```
public Func<LoginResult> ShowLoginDialogDelegate;
```

In your View you define the function that will be called:

```
private LoginResult ShowLoginDialog()
{
    LoginResult result;
    // show a dialog and get the login data
    return result;
}
```

Then you "connect" the delegate and method in the View:

```
_viewModel = new MyViewModel();
DataContext = _viewModel;
_viewModel.ShowLoginDialogDelegate += ShowLoginDialog;
```

And now you can use it in your ViewModel e.g. when a command is executed like that:

```
LoginResult result = ShowLoginDialogDelegate();
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier answer is to control it's visibility through a View State which with a little manipulation can be made to work through databinding allowing the view model to display the "Logon Page" state when required.

I just recently wrote about this for the Silverlight/XNA series which you can view [here](http://xna-uk.net/blogs/darkgenesis/archive/2011/09/22/xna-to-silverxna-part-6-adding-a-bit-of-flash.aspx).

It would be much simplier if the SL4 DataEventrigger was available but hay ho.